# Set value of an object inside an array in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I want to define an object inside an array inside a for loop:

```
var test = [{}];

for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ test[j]['name'] = "Jonh Lennon"; };

console.log(test[0]['name']);
```

When i try to do this, i get the error "cannot set property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: And how do you declare test?, can you show your code? (angular component code)

Comment: Please show more code, how you do it in Angularjs component/directive/contoller, right now all you are showing is Javascript code, and that code if it works in vanillaJS it will work in AngularJs because AngularJs is still Javascript framework. Your problem lies somewhere else and without code it's impossible to debug.

Comment: One thing I can see is that you're using let, and that's does not create a function scoped variable, it creates a block scoped variable, if you declare it anywhere inside { ... } then it exists only in those bracket - block scope, you may have issue with that, try just switching let with var, might solve your problem right away.

Comment: I just pasted this code in my angular app - works fine, no errors

Comment: i just realised it only causes problem inside my "for" loop. Take a look at my edited code. Does it still work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only test[0] is defined as an object literal in your code. So as your loop increments past 0, test[j](where j is between 1 and 9 inclusive) will return undefined.

Here's a quick fix that will have return an array of object literals with a key value pair of {'name':'Jonh Lennon'}.

```
var test = [{}];

for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ 
 test[j] = {};
 test[j]['name'] = "Jonh Lennon";   
};

console.log(test); // Log all john lennons
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [];
for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ 
  test[j] = [];
  test[j]['name'] = "Jonh Lennon";
};

console.log(test[0]['name']);
```